# Chef: Ohai attribute persistence

Tags: postgresql, chef-infra

Chef Server 12.2.0-1.

I'm trying to find a way to query Ohai node attributes from the PostgreSQL database. Having browsed through the table schemas and data, I'm not seeing any tables that would contain those attributes.

Are these attributes stored on Chef server? Is there a way to view them remotely via a database query or a REST call?

List of opscode_chef tables:

```
checksums
clients
containers
cookbook_artifact_version_checksums
cookbook_artifact_versions
cookbook_artifacts
cookbook_version_checksums
cookbook_versions
cookbooks
data_bag_items
data_bags
environments
groups
keys
node_policy
nodes
opc_customers
opc_users
org_migration_state
org_user_associations
org_user_invites
orgs
policies
policy_groups
policy_revisions
policy_revisions_policy_groups_association
roles
sandboxed_checksums
users
```

**UPDATE 1**: Thanks to @Tensibai. 
Attributes are stored in table `nodes`, column `serialized_object`. The column `serialized_object` is gzip encoded.

Java code to fetch attributes in json:

```
String query = "SELECT name, serialized_object FROM nodes";
PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement(query);
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
while (rs.next()) {
    String name = rs.getString("name");
    byte[] arr = rs.getBytes("serialized_object");
    byte[] out = unzip(arr);
    System.out.println(name + " : " + new String(out));
}

public static byte[] unzip(byte[] in) throws IOException{
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    FileUtils.copy(new GZIPInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(in)), out);
    return out.toByteArray();
}
```

Sample attributes: https://gist.github.com/rodionos/cb744155539699b5c348

I'm not an expert in PostgreSQL. A better solution would probably be to enable a native decompression function as described here: https://github.com/chef/chef-server/issues/8#issuecomment-99152808

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ? the attributes are stored as json within nodes. The usual way to use them is in search which takes advantage of flat indexing in solr. Without the use case, it's impossible to give a correct advice.

Comment: I need to load attributes for indexing in another database, not solr, without going after each node directly. Looks like attributes are not stored in PostgreSQL which is too bad. Is there a rest endpoint that would allow someone to fetch attributes via the Chef server.

Comment: FWIW they are in postgres, in a bytea entry of a serialized object wich is a compressed json according to the [erchef code](https://github.com/chef/chef-server/blob/master/src/oc_erchef/apps/chef_objects/src/chef_node.erl#L313). You may hae a look [here](https://github.com/davisp/jiffy) if you want to see how the node binary is transformed to json object. I still don't see the use case of re indexing the attributes in another DB instead of taking advantage of solr...

Comment: And sofor your API question, you can show all nodes with their attributes by calling `knife search node "*" -l` or `knife search node "*" -a "attribute_key_you_want"` This will be  a very huge list, and will display attributes for all nodes when displaying the node.

Comment: @Tensibai Thanks! I was able to query the attributes from the database. Please post your comment as answer.

Comment: It was more a guidance, your edit seems to be a better answer, you're allowed to answer yourself ;)

Comment: @Tensibai Thx again. I'll keep the question open in case someone figures out a workable solution using a native gzip decompression function in PostgreSQL.